# shell script to read filename from a text file line by line and to confirm they are present in two different directories

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i have a requirement to read a list of file from a text file and to search those file in two different directories in unix,if it is not present i need to print the file name.I have written following shell script

```
#!usr/bin/ksh
while 
read -r filename ; do
if [ -e $filename ] || [ -e /demo/bin/$filename ];
then
echo "File Found!!!! "
else
echo "not found $filename"
fi
done < "$1"
```

But the problem is if i hardcode the file name in script it is showing File Found.
but without hardcoding the name if i execute same script same file name it is showing not found.
I have stored all file name which i need to search in different file which name as abc.txt.

i am executing above script like  sh isFileExist.sh abc.txt

Comment: What does this have to do with `java`?

Comment: Doesn't the list contain MSWin line ends?

Comment: Maybe rewrite the loop as follows:


```
    for filename in $@
    do
       if [ -e $filename ] || [ -e /demo/bin/$filename ]; then
          echo "File Found!!!! "
       else
          echo "not found $filename"
       fi
    done
```

(formatting is not working for me atm)

Comment: Offtopic: Not `#!usr/bin/ksh` bit `#!/usr/bin/ksh`.

Comment: When the filename has spaces, you will need quotes like `[ -e "$filename" ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a test directories and files to show how it can be done.

Create directories `dir1 and`dir2`

```
mkdir -p dir{1..2}
```

Check the directories.

```
ls 

dir1  dir2
```

Create the files.

```
touch dir{1..2}/{1..10}.txt
```

Check the files.

```
ls dir{1..2}/
dir1/:
10.txt  1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt  5.txt  6.txt  7.txt  8.txt  9.txt

dir2/:
10.txt  1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt  5.txt  6.txt  7.txt  8.txt  9.txt
```

Creat the contents of the file.

```
printf '%s\n' {1..10}.txt > list_of_files.txt
printf '%s\n' {a..c} >> list_of_files.txt
```

Check the contents of the file.

```
cat list_of_files.txt
```

The output is

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt
6.txt
7.txt
8.txt
9.txt
10.txt
a
b
c
```

The variable `foo` is `dir1` and the variable `bar` is `dir2` in the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

foo=dir1
bar=dir2

while read -r files_in_text; do
  if  [ ! -e "$foo"/"$files_in_text" ] && [ ! -e "$bar"/"$files_in_text" ]; then
    printf 'files %s and %s does not exists!\n' "$foo"/"$files_in_text" "$bar"/"$files_in_text"
  else
    printf 'files %s and %s does exists.\n' "$foo"/"$files_in_text" "$bar"/"$files_in_text"
  fi
done < list_of_files.txt
```

The output should be

```
files dir1/1.txt and dir2/1.txt does exists.
files dir1/2.txt and dir2/2.txt does exists.
files dir1/3.txt and dir2/3.txt does exists.
files dir1/4.txt and dir2/4.txt does exists.
files dir1/5.txt and dir2/5.txt does exists.
files dir1/6.txt and dir2/6.txt does exists.
files dir1/7.txt and dir2/7.txt does exists.
files dir1/8.txt and dir2/8.txt does exists.
files dir1/9.txt and dir2/9.txt does exists.
files dir1/10.txt and dir2/10.txt does exists.
files dir1/a and dir2/a does not exists!
files dir1/b and dir2/b does not exists!
files dir1/c and dir2/c does not exists!
```

Comment: problem i faced because of i copied text from windows machine into the linux machine and issue was because of MsWin Line ends..Thanks @choroba for comment.